# incompatible conversion error in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

Compiler is complaining about incompatible variable types stored in array.
This happens, when I'm trying to convert characters from argv[1] to uppercase (first for loop). Similar error occurs in second for loop,
where I'd like to convert chars to their ASCII equivalent and subtract 64 from it. What do?

```
//converts chars in argv[1] to uppercase letters
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++){
    argv[i] = toupper(argv[i]);
    }

//converts chars in argv[1] to numbers 
int key[strlen(argv[1])];
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i<n; i++){
    key[i]= argv[i]-64;
```

Error mesagges:

```
incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'string' (aka 'char *') from 'int' [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
```

and

```
incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'string' (aka 'char *') [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
```

Comment: `toupper()` converts a single `char`, not a string.   Suggest `argv[1][i] = toupper((unsigned char) argv[1][i]);`

Comment: argv[i] is a pointer, you want argv[1][i].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [toupper function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057899/toupper-function)

Comment: How could I be so blind. Thank you, pals!

Comment: Void * values cannot be deferentiate.

Comment: Take ` n = strlen(argv[1])` out of the loop initialization and put it in the main code. Then it does not have to be repeated in the second loop initialization.

Comment: @jurhas: You mean "dereferenced"? And the `argv` argument of `main` is not `void *` (nor `void **`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you mean

```
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++){
    argv[1][i] = toupper( ( unsigned char )argv[1][i]);
    }

//converts chars in argv[1] to numbers 
int key[strlen(argv[1])];
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i<n; i++){
    key[i]= argv[1][i]-64;
```